# similar posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im using this method to pick similar posts, which i have placed in `post.rb`. Now I'm having two problems 1.is I'm getting an error. 2. how would i implement this into the view or controller to getting the similar posts?:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 def similar_posts(post)
   title_keywords = post.title.split(' ')
   Post.all.to_a.sort do |post1, post2|
     post1_title_intersection = post1.body.split(' ') & title_keywords
     post2_title_intersection = post2.body.split(' ') & title_keywords

     post2_title_intersection.length <=> post1_title_intersection.length
   end[0..9]
 end
end
```

The error I'm getting:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end Post.all.to_a.sort |post1, post2| ^ 
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `do` before your block's arguments:

```
Post.all.to_a.sort do |post1, post2|
end
```

---

However, there's a major flaw with your approach (*that's unrelated to your syntax issue at hand*): you're gonna load in memory **every single post in your database**. That's a terrible idea.

Instead, use some kind of full-text like search, use a separate table for tabs, use some external service like ElasticSearch, etc. Those are made for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. You've forgotten `do` here:

   ```
   Post.all.to_a.sort |post1, post2|
   ```
2. Implement it into the service or model, but not to a controller or a view. Because it just strictly waste your code. For service you can then issue a delayed operation to find required post in background. So to use delayed services you can use, for example, gem [`service`](https://github.com/krautcomputing/services). Organizing in such way your service operation you can when use cache facility like `redis` to issue a request and then store results of proceeding that ones.

   If you'll use it in a model declare it as a method:

   ```
   class Post
      def similar_posts
         title_keywords = self.title.split(' ')
         Post.all.sort do |post1, post2|
         post1_title_intersection = post1.body.split(' ') & title_keywords
         post2_title_intersection = post2.body.split(' ') & title_keywords

         post2_title_intersection.length <=> post1_title_intersection.length
      end[0..9]
   end
   ```

   Then use it like follows:

   ```
   @posts = Post.find_by_id(params[:id]).similar_posts
   ```

But since it is just for display, seems to be better to add it to [decorator](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) as a method. Also to increase access yo the result of that you might use `redis`.

Comment: iv used scaffold to generate a simple app for posts, how would i implement this to show the similar posts? thanks

Comment: @user5724342 it depends on what do you wish to see and where

Comment: i would like to view it on in show for each post and just the title. Iv implemented the code into my model but I'm not sure how to use it in my view?

Comment: @user5724342 show you resulted model with the code in the question. Note since it is like a scope, create a scope for this.

Answer (score 0):

You missing **do**

Change

```
Post.all.to_a.sort |post1, post2|
to 
Post.all.to_a.sort do |post1, post2|
```

This will resolve syntax error